# Implement ApiResource security filter rule for collectionOperations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

Is it possible to implement ApiResource security over an Entity so that a GET request without entity id (that is, a collection operation) returns only items that match the current authenticated user (or, for that purpose, any other rule that must be checked against each entity)?

My implementation so far:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')"},
 *     collectionOperations={"get"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or object == user"}},
 *     itemOperations={"get"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or object == user"}},
 *     )
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id;

   // ...

}
```

The code above is working for item operations, but not for collection operators, that is, assuming user id. 1 (not an admin) is authenticated:

- GET `/api/user/1` returns 200 OK with user #1 data (as desired)
- GET `/api/user/2` returns 403 FORBIDDEN (as desired, user 1 should not be able to get other user's data).
- GET `/api/user` returns 403 FORBIDDEN (**NOT** as desired, desired behavior would be returning a list containing only entities that pass the rule, that is, user #1's data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Doctrine Extension](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/) for this. It's not a security concern, you want not to restrict access to the resource but to modify the returned results.

E.g., hastily modifying the example on the linked docs:

```
final class CurrentUserExtension implements QueryCollectionExtensionInterface
{

    public function __construct(private Security $security)
    {
    }

    public function applyToCollection(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null): void
    {
        if (User::class !== $resourceClass
            || $this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')
            || null === $user = $this->security->getUser())
        {
            return;
        }

        $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
        $queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf('%s.id = :current_user', $rootAlias));
        $queryBuilder->setParameter('current_user', $user->getId());
    }

}
```